# How to draw a normal curve in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice

How to calculate the distribution, mean and standard deviation for drawing a normal curve distribution chart (bell shape curve) in Libreoffice Calc?

Comment: Lots of us are glad to help.  Please attach the document and lots more detail.  It is not clear what you are trying to do. And not clear what your data is. More detail=more help

Comment: Now can u look into my question and plz answer

Answer (score 5):

I created a data set with 24 numbers. Then random numbers between 0 and 11. Then calculated the Normal Distribution using the formula shown.

=NORM.DIST(B8,AVERAGE($B$8:$B$31),STDEV($B$8:$B$31),0)

All functions are medium well documented. Go to Insert>Function and search.

[image]

https://mega.nz/file/BZJnBCjQ#0m3x8VZRTJ8b2b5LO6Co5DIUNtrhnFHJUnKWb2Fk49I

Comment: Thanks a lot walt

Comment: @walttheboss - I managed to create column C, but I can't follow you further. What did you put exactly in columns D and E?

Comment: Statistics was never my to my liking, but this is impressive and well worth an upvote.

Comment: Amen to that.  The course in college nearly killed me.  Thanks for the comment.